# Aggregate JSON in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, group-by, sum, pivot

I have a json column with entries that look like this:

```
{
  "pages": "64",
  "stats": {
    "1": { "200": "55", "400": "4" },
    "2": { "200": "1" },
    "3": { "200": "1", "404": "13" },
  }
}
```

The 'stats' are collections (of various sizes) containing http status codes versus counts.

I would like to aggregate the stats into two calculated columns - one for the total number of `200` responses and the other for the total number of responses (including `200`s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two lateral joins to unnest the inner objects, then do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    sum(z.cnt::int) no_responses,
    sum(z.cnt::int) filter(where z.code::int = 200) no_200_responses
from mytable t
cross join lateral jsonb_each(t.data -> 'stats') as x(kx, obj)
cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(x.obj) as z(code, cnt)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=194484460d24aa697d335005eda7937d)**:

```
no_responses | no_200_responses
-----------: | ---------------:
          74 |               57
```

Comment: that's really close - thanks! - but I don't need to aggregate the results for all rows, I need the totals for each row as a calculated column

Comment: @WillJenkins: ok, I was wondering. If the primary key of your table is `id`, then you just need to `group by id` at the end of the query (you might also want to add this column to the `select` list).

Comment: boom! that's it, nice one